# Failed to execute script due to unhandled exception: No module named ttkwidgets

Tags: pyinstaller, ttkwidgets

I created an executable from a py file that used ttkwidgets

```
import tkinter as tk
import work_logger_database
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteEntry

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x300')

items = work_logger_database.show_all()


stored_projects_list = list(set([items[i][2] for i in range(len(items))]))

#or:
#example_list = ['Hello', 'World']

project_entry = AutocompleteEntry(root, completevalues=stored_projects_list)
project_entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='W')

root.mainloop()
```

and when I open the exe I get what is shown in this image

[image]

I also got a warning:

```
WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'numpy'. Please take care they do not conflict.
```

I'm not sure if that's relevant

I tried a solution in creating the exe that didn't work:

```
pyinstaller work_logger.py --onefile -w --hidden-import=ttkwidgets --hidden-import=ttkwidgets.autocomplete
```

I also tried:

```
pyinstaller work_logger.py --onefile -w --hidden-import=ttkwidgets
```

Comment: create a [example]

Comment: is that better?

Comment: It works fine for me with just `pyinstaller -F filename.py`

Comment: I tried this and I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttkwidgets'", but in a console this time

Answer (score 0):

Had the same ModuleNotFoundError: 'ttkwidgets' creating an executable of one of my scripts.
Worked after (re-)installing ttkwidgets on my system:

```
pip install ttkwidgets
```